# Change woocommerce 'coupon does not exist! error message

Tags: php, woocommerce, coupon

I would like to change the default woocommerce error message that I get when client enters a coupon that does not exist `Coupon “%s” does not exist!`. Is it possible to do this directly in the function.php file of my child theme? If so it would be greatly appreciated to get some suggestions as to the code to use and where. I have tried to add the below code to the funtion.php file, but it didn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_error','coupon_error_message_change', 10, 3 );

public function coupon_error_message_change( $err, $err_code, $parm )
{
    switch ( $err_code ) {
        case 105:
            /* translators: %s: coupon code */
            $err = sprintf( __( 'Coupon "%s" does not test!', 'woocommerce' ), $parm->get_code() );
            break;
    }
    return $err;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_error','coupon_error_message_change',10,3 );

function coupon_error_message_change($err, $err_code, $WC_Coupon) {
    switch ( $err_code ) {
        case $WC_Coupon::E_WC_COUPON_NOT_EXIST:
            $err = 'your message';
    }
    return $err;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Talita! Thank you very much for provided answer. Would be great to see some information about where to put this chunk of code and why it works like that.

Comment: Thanks Talita, this worked perfectly! Alex, I have pasted the code provide by Talita in the funtion.php file located in my child-theme.

Comment: Actually, I did some further testing and I just wanted to let you know that this code conflicts with all the other coupon error messages. So for example if the coupon is expired, no message will be displayed anymore...

Comment: Sorry, @Manu... I haven't really tested enough, but I edited the answer and I think it works now.

Comment: Hello Talita, indeed this works. Thank you very much for your help!